# Exporting artboards to PDF at @2x

Tags: sketch-app

Is there a way to have Sketch export all artboards to a single PDF at 2x?

Comment: PDF should be vector anyway so why would you need it at 2x?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the plug-in "PDF Export — Sketch Plugin" with the option "Export as PNGs into PDF" which allow you to set a resolution multiplier.

This will enable you export all artboards to a single pdf file at 2x.

You can download the plug-in from the github repo [here](https://github.com/DWilliames/PDF-export-sketch-plugin).

Comment: This is indeed a great plugin to have, I use it daily.

Answer (score 0):

You can change exporting file format here and resize it as 2x.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Nope, there isn’t a way to export all artboards to a PDF, but there is a way to export artboards as PNGs or PDFs, then combine them into a single PDF using Automator.

1. Select all the artboards you’d like to export.
2. Click the `+` near the bottom right of the window to add an export item.
3. Set it to `PDF` and `2x` (not quite sure why you want it at 2×?).
4. Click the export toolbar button near the top right of the window.

[image: Sketch exporting]

5. Open `Automator` (it’s in your Applications folder).
6. Find the `Combined PDF Pages` action and drag it to the pane on the right.
7. Select all your PDFs in the Finder and drag them above the `Combined PDF Pages` item you just added.
8. Click run.

You should now have a combined PDF on your desktop, with all your artboards.

[image: Automator]

Answer (score 0):

The PDF Export — Sketch Plugin works well for larger artboards.  Unless I'm missing something, it does not work well with smaller artboards because it aligns them vertically (and also by name, which may/may not help depending on your case).  So if you hundreds of 24x24 artboads like icons, you'll end up with 30 page PDF.

I'm still looking for a solution but for now the quickest way for me was to give all the artboards no name and then take several screenshots and piece together.  I was able to do this with 6 screenshots.  I'm only using this to share with my Team so super high resolution was not important. If high res is important, don't use this method.